# How to  get a list of installed software packages?

Tags: 12.04, re-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to list all installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages)

I am on a "grown" system. My initial setup was using Ubuntu 9.04.

But now with the 12.04 Update I got stuck. My System is freezing or wired errors occour.

I want to reinstall my system on a clean partition.

How can I get a list of the packages I installed in my system? I want a list with the base packages not all the dependecies, so I can install all packages on my clean install again with the correct (maybe new) dependencies.

I other words: I want to retrieve a list of all packages installed with apt-get directly.
Not the ones it additionally installs with these packages.

Thanks!